How to I set up Looker Studio Pro for a Google Project?
When I am trying to set up the Looker Studio Pro I am receiving the following error:
enter image description here
Am I missing something?
Is there a server that needs to be set up on the back end server that needs to be created or are there other requirements that I am currently not fulfilling?

You have included a link to an image.  See if you can inline the image so that the reader doesn't have to go and click through it themselves.    Maybe also describe the steps you performed in as much detail as possible describing how you got here.  What searches/examinations have you done already to self solve the problem?
